# Grabing text from non java application

Tags: java, linux, text, textarea

Is it possible to grab textarea using java from another non-java application?

Known way is OCR with java.awt.Robot in my opinion is too complex and non effective if grabbed area is in the minimized window.

P.S. Linux environment is preferred but not mandatory for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no easy way to do this using Java's standard API.