# Copy highlighted text from non-native java application

Tags: java, text, highlight

I'm looking to build an application that copy's the highlighted text from a non-native java application, for example your web browser and then does some operations on it. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762463/grabing-text-from-non-java-application) question, I found out that there is no easy way to do this through native Java but are there other non native libraries that I can use?

Comment: please one Q: `highlighted text` is 1) stylled/decorated text or 2) selection created by mouse/keyboard

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry, I don't understand. My question is regarding copying text through some keyboard/mouse action.

Comment: by default there isn't any issue to copy selected text from (for example) ms word to JTextArea, see [more in Q&A about System ClipBoard](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+[swing]+clipboard), but without, you lost all decorations or stylles

Comment: @mKorbel I don't need decorations/styles. I just need the text.

Comment: well, thanks, please to remove tags highlight, highlighting and then to add clipboard :-)

Comment: @mKorbel But, I need to get the text that is highlighted. Therefore, the tags are required right?